# Automatic mapping for public fields instead of properties

Tags: csvhelper

My data models consist of public fields instead of properties. I'm keen to use CSVHelper's automatic mapping to write these fields into a .csv file. This works fine for properties - but fields appear to be excluded.

The code below works fine when I provide a ClassMap<> - but that seems inconvenient re: long term maintenance. Is there a way to have it automatically map fields as it would for properties?

```
void Main()
{
    var records = new List<Foo>
    {
        new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "one" },
    };
    
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter("path\\to\\file.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<FooMap>();
        csv.WriteRecords(records);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
}

public sealed class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo> {
    public TechMap() {
        AutoMap(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        // I'm very keen to avoid having to map 
        // every field that's to be exported.
        Map(m => m.Id).Name("Id");
        Map(m => m.Name).Name("Name");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution here is to specify fields as member type. A custom configuration can be passed into the `CsvWriter` constructor.

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) {
    MemberTypes = MemberTypes.Fields
};
```

This works like a charm.